# How to Change an EditorFor to a DropdownFor in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I have a controller, model and view and I am trying to make an already existing @html.editoFor to a @html.dropdownfor so I can limit the user to select only three possible values (Open, Close, Onhold).

To be more specific, I want to change the input box created by an editorFor in my Create and Edit action of my controller to a selection box if possible.

If that isnt possible, then I was wondering how can I  provide the model with three default values to accept so only those values can be submited to the DB...

Comment: See my DDL tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the EditorFor, but unfortunately it's based on the type of the property, so if you have a `string` in your model, and you change the EditorFor, you're changing it for all strings where you use EditorFor.

If you create a custom object, containing the value, and maybe the three possible values, it's easy to create a custom EditorFor for this.

Take a look here:
http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/10/overriding-displayfor-and-editorfor-to-create-custom-outputs-for-mvc/

(This is for version 3, but I haven't read anywhere that it has been changed for version 4, so give it a go)

Comment: I have noticed the type property thing. One may thing it would be simple to switch from editorfor to dropdownfor but it isnt.. In the meantime, I noticed that a dropdown is automatically generated for my bit data type attributes and only the tru,false,not assigned options are provided in the dropdown.... Is there any way to customize the selection options???